# Why HttpServletRequest object does not have getServletConfig() method?

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, servletconfig

I am new to Java Servlets and while going through one tutorial I found this.

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
```

When I tried using the request object to get the ServletContext object it also worked.

```
ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
```

But I could not find a method in the HttpServletRequest class to get ServletConfig.

```
ServletConfig config = request.getServletConfig();
```

This is not correct as `HttpServletRequest` class does not have `getServletCofig()` method.

Why is it so?
I know that ServletConfig is acts as a local to a servlet while ServletContext acts as a global to all the servlets in the application. Is it related to this any how?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's on the [Servlet](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/Servlet.html#getServletConfig--).

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I want to understand why it is not in [ServletRequest](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html).